# T-SQL FOR XML EXPLICIT - add attribute "xsi:nil" to elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to generate XML files to third-party specifications. The one case where I'm having trouble is where there is a NULL column. The spec says that along with the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute, there needs to be a reason attribute.

The node would need to look like this:

```
<Phone xsi:nil="true" Reason="none" />
```

I can generate nodes with attributes and values, but not `xsi:nil` with an additional attribute.

This generates the proper format for everything except the `xsi:nil` attribute:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    [Id] [int],
    [OwnerId] [int],
    [Number] [char](12),
    [Type] [char](4),
    [Reason] [char](4))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    (1,1,'414-555-1212','cell',NULL),
    (2,2,NULL,NULL,'None'),
    (3,3,'202-555-1212','work',NULL),
    (4,3,'212-555-1212','cell',NULL)

SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS [Root!1],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!OwnerId],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Type],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Reason],
    NULL AS [Phone!2]
union all
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    OwnerId,
    Type,
    Reason,
    Number
FROM
    @T
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

The output is:

```
<Root>
    <Phone OwnerId="1" Type="cell">414-555-1212</Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="2" Reason="None" />
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="work">202-555-1212</Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="cell">212-555-1212</Phone>
</Root>
```

I can use ELEMENTXSINIL to get the proper treatment of NULL values with the namespace defined in the root node with this, but the phone number is a different element:

```
SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS [Root!1],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!OwnerId],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Type],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Reason],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Number!ELEMENTXSINIL]
union all
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    OwnerId,
    Type,
    Reason,
    Number
FROM
    @T
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Phone OwnerId="1" Type="cell">
        <Number>414-555-1212</Number>
    </Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="2" Reason="None">
        <Number xsi:nil="true" />
    </Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="work">
        <Number>202-555-1212</Number>
    </Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="cell">
        <Number>212-555-1212</Number>
    </Phone>
</Root>
```

The specs are very consistent and `Reason` as an attribute will only appear on NULL values. I can do some post processing and add `xsi:nil="true"` to those nodes and the namespace definition in the root element, but I'd prefer to get this step to do it correctly.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there some business reason not mentioned that you'd need to use `FOR XML EXPLICIT` here? It would be easier to use `FOR XML PATH(...), ELEMENTS XSINIL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're committed to using `FOR XML EXPLICIT`, which doesn't really make for understandable and maintainable code, then you can add an namespace declaration to the `Root` element and manually add the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute like the following:

```sql
SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    NULL AS [Root!1],
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS [Root!1!xmlns:xsi],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!OwnerId],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Type],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!Reason],
    NULL AS [Phone!2!xsi:nil],
    NULL AS [Phone!2]
union all
SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    OwnerId,
    Type,
    Reason,
    CASE WHEN Number IS NULL THEN 'true' END,
    Number
FROM
    @T
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

Which produces the output:

```xml
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Phone OwnerId="1" Type="cell">414-555-1212</Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="2" Reason="None" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="work">202-555-1212</Phone>
    <Phone OwnerId="3" Type="cell">212-555-1212</Phone>
</Root>
```

The same output can be produced with the same manual attribute management using `FOR XML PATH` like the following:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi
)
SELECT
    OwnerId AS [@OwnerId],
    Type AS [@Type],
    Reason AS [@Reason],
    CASE WHEN Number IS NULL THEN 'true' END AS [@xsi:nil],
    Number AS [data()] -- or [node()] or [text()]
  FROM @T
FOR XML PATH ('Phone'), ROOT('Root');
```

Although you might have expected that the above could be simplified with `ELEMENTS XSINIL` for some reason `FOR XML PATH` doesn't recognize the `null` output from `data()`, `node()` nor `text()` to add the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute itself.

To use `FOR XML PATH` with `ELEMENTS XSINIL` more simply we can rely on a different technique - empty element names get excluded from the output:

```sql
SELECT
    OwnerId AS [Phone/@OwnerId],
    Type AS [Phone/@Type],
    Reason AS [Phone/@Reason],
    Number AS [Phone]
  FROM @T
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Root'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer. I've avoided using XML PATH as other examples I've seen add the xsi:nil namespace definition to each node. Yours places it in the root node as it should be. I agree that XML PATH is a much cleaner way of formatting the output and will be looking to complete my project with PATH going forward.